# Proof verification: If $M$ is maximal, $R/M$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

Let $M$ be maximal, we want to show that $R/M$ is a field. To do this we wish to show that for all $a\in R$, where $a+M\not\equiv 0+M$,  $a+M \in R/M$ is a unit.

So we have already excluded $a\in M$, so as to avoid $a+M\equiv 0+M$.

**1.** Is it valid to exclude these elements? Surely these cannot be invertible in $R/M$

Now we have two cases:

Case 1: $a$ is a unit in $R$, then $\exists a^{-1}\in R$ such that $(a+M)(a^{-1}+M)=1+M$ and $a+M\in R/M$ is invertible.

Case 2: $a$ is not a unit in $R$, and thus $\langle a\rangle \subsetneq R$. Then $M\subseteq\langle a\rangle \cup M$, but $a\not\in M$ and $M$ is maximal, contradition, then $a\in M$ or $a$ is invertible in $R$.

So we have that either $a\in M$ or $a+M$ is invertible in $R/M$. Then all nonzero elements of $R/M$ are invertible, and $R/M$ is therefore a field.

**2.** Is my argument valid?

Comment: Your argument is not valid.  Take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=2\mathbb{Z}$.  Then the element $3\in R$ is not in $M$, but it's not a unit either.

Comment: To answer #$1$-yes, it is valid to exclude these, as they all map to $0$ in $R/M$, and in a field we do not have to find an inverse for $0$ (none exists). For case $2$, you're close-but no cigar-$\langle a \rangle \cup M$ need not be an ideal (in fact it usually isn't).

Comment: @DavidWheeler Argh, perhaps substituting with $\langle M,a\rangle$ fixes this?

Comment: That is the substance of Gregory Grant's answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a\in R$ where $a\not\in M$.  Then $(a)+M$ is an ideal properly containing $M$.  Thus $(a)+M=R$.  So $\exists$ $b\in R$ and $m\in M$ such that $1=m+ab$.  Then $\overline b$ is the multiplicative inverse of $\overline a$.  Thus every non-zero element in $R/M$ has an inverse.

Comment: Thanks. That is very clean.

Comment: Sorry. I thought I understood this, but when I was trying to write it up unassisted, I wasn't sure that $\langle a\rangle + M$ was even an ideal. Surely $M\subset \langle a\rangle + M$ as sets, but if $\langle a\rangle + M$ is not an ideal, I don't know it is the ring/

Comment: @Thomas $(a)+M$ is the ideal generated by $a$ and $M$ so it is an ideal.  It consists of elements of the form $ax+m$ where $x\in R$ and $m\in M$.